# Symmetry group of FLRW metric

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, vector-fields

$$ g = dt^2 - a^2(t) (dx^2+dy^2+dz^2) = dt^2-a^2(t)(dr^2+r^2d\Omega^2)$$

So this is my metric. What is the symmetry group of it? 
I think that my Killing vectors are 3 translation vectors: $$K_i = \partial_i$$
but also we have this rotational symmetry. So do we also have $SO(3)$ or even $O(3)$ Killing vectors? Is there something more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To some extent Your answered the question already! Look at the basic postulates of cosmology, these are homogeneity and isotropy of space-time. Isotropy implies three Killing vectors (SO(3)) and homogeneity gives another three killing vectors (for translation in three spatial direction). Therefore altogether six Killing vectors. Remember we not considering static universe.

In fact by solving Killing equations for these six Killing vectors, one can derive FRW metric. For an account you can check Ryder's General relativity (Cosmology chapter).