# How to prove that Hubble's law is consistent with homogeneity by using a translation?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, metric-tensor, space-expansion

Assuming that Hubble's law
$$v=H_{0}\,r$$
works for some specific point and that the universe has FLRW metric
$${\displaystyle -c^{2}\mathrm {d} \tau ^{2}=-c^{2}\mathrm {d} t^{2}+{a(t)}^{2}(\mathrm{d}r^2 + r^2 \mathrm{d}\mathbf{\Omega}^2)}, \quad \text{where } \mathrm{d}\mathbf{\Omega}^2 = \mathrm{d}\theta^2 + \sin^2 \theta \, \mathrm{d}\phi^2$$

can we prove that Hubble's law works **for all other space points** at a fixed cosmic time?

I want to understand how the Hubble equation can be transformed to another point. Intuitively it is understandable since the distance between 2 space points varies proportionally to $a(t)$.

Edit: As mentioned in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/321935/264772), we can't do finite translations in a general curved space-time, but in flat FLRW I think we can.

Comment: It's simplest if you rewrite the 3d line element in cartesian like coordinates, then you can freely choose your origin

Comment: @KP99 that is what I had in mind when I mentioned 'Intuitively'. But as I mentioned in the question I want to do **a translation transformation**.

Comment: This (translation invariance) comes out almost immediately in Cartesian coordinates.. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/261075/symmetry-group-of-flrw-metric

Comment: @Eletie I know that those cartesian vector fields are killing vector fields and because of that if we do an infinitesimal transformation along those directions the metric is invariant. But I want to do a finite transformation along those directions.

Comment: A finite translation is just repeated infinitesimal shifts. So yes, because we have these kvf's, which you mentioned are infinitesimal generators of symmetries, we know we have isometries. We can use the kvf's to reconstruct what it means to do 'translations'. In this case it does just come down to looking at the spatial coordinate invariance of the metric - I'm not sure what you want to explicitly see differently? (A translation is just a diffeomorphism after all)

Comment: @Eletie I want to understand how Hubble's law transforms under a finite translation within flat 3D subspace of FLRW spacetime with $k=0$.

Comment: @KasiReddySreemanReddy You seem to have it the wrong way around, Hubble's law comes *from* the metric. If you're assuming the metric (which is literally isotropy and homogeneity) then you automatically get Hubble's law at *all* points.